# What does it mean if a professor suggests to contact in future?

Tags: masters, communication

I am a final year Computer Science student from South Asia and expected to graduate by August 2017. I thought of starting to contact professors for masters program from now. Today I received a reply from the professor I mailed first. He said,

> Thank you for your interest. I would suggest you to contact me once you have graduated.

What can I infer from this kind of reply? And another question: Is it too early to start to apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can infer from this type of reply that you should contact him once you have graduated.

There are many reasons for this:

- If you're genuinely interested, you'll follow up when the time comes.
- The last year of a program can be hugely impactful in either good or bad ways on a student's preparation.
- You may be outside the application window for his program, which puts talking to new students low on the priority list. Similarly, if its a competitive process for admitting people into his lab, he'll be wanting to compare you to other interested students.
- Funding is a time-variable thing. Whether or not he has room for a student in his lab, can pay for them, etc. might be very different now and when you'd actually arrive.

Among others. It's not necessarily too early to start applying places, but sometimes you may get answers like that.

Comment: Actually I want to target Spring 2018 semester. What should be the ideal time for contacting him again then? Immediately after graduation or sometime later? Fall 2017 admission at the university will be in between  my graduation and Spring 2018.

Comment: I'd ask their administrators.

Answer (score 0):

A lot can happen in the last year of a program. If I had to guess, this is professor lingo for "Don't count your chickens before they're hatched." Complete your current degree (or progress to the point where you are absolutely 100% sure you will be receiving your degree) before you start asking professors about Master's programs.

I don't necessarily agree with this line of thought, but then again, I'm not a professor.